# React - Push array using usestate hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I am making "Load more" which fetches 10 projects from the backend every time button is clicked.

I don't understand I'm facing this basic yet weird issue.

> **ISSUE(example)**

```js
const [ projectArray, setProjectArray ] = useState([ { id: 1 } ]) // original state
//
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/project/explore/${page}`);
console.log(data); // returns array of objects 
if (data.length > 0) {
   setProjectArray(array => [...array, data]);
}
console.log(projectArray) 
// This^^ returns >>> [ {id: 1}, [ { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is also an array so you should expand that as well

```
   setProjectArray(array => [...array, ...data]);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case, `data` is already an array, so it is working as intended. Adding an array inside the existing array.

You'll probably want to use `concat()` to join the two arrays together.

Try `setProject(concat(projectArray,data));`